# One liner for listing contents of file within war file

Tags: java, jar

I need to be able to read the contents of a file (say MANIFEST) within a jar file. 
Currently I do this by extracting the contents of the file and then listing it

```
${JAVA_HOME}/bin/jar xvf SOME_WAR_FILE.war META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
cat META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

Is it possible to do this using a one liner, without extracting the contents ?

Comment: Is this file deployed or not? If it's deployed, it's contents should already be extracted and can be read directly (I know this is possible w/ JBoss and WebLogic)

Comment: I need this to perform some validation before I startup my app server, so I cannot wait until I startup the app server.

Comment: And just to clarify, your requirements are to do this without extracting the contents physically? Or that you don't care how it gets done, but you want a one line solution?

Comment: without extracting the contents

Comment: I'm not on my dev machine so I can't try it, but how about the solution suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14778980/how-to-read-content-of-the-zipped-file-without-extracting-in-java

Comment: Problem is that I have over 1000 servers. If I write a java program, I will need to copy it over to all of them.

Comment: First, 1,000 servers is a bit ridiculous. Second, what kind of solution DO you want then, if not a programmatic one?

Comment: @Kevin - my solution below uses a standard tool that should already be on your machine(s), it displays the file contents without extracting it, yet Kon seems to think it's wrong and deserves a downvote. Can you tell me what about my answer does not satisfy your requirements? Kon's comment on my answer was... less than informative.

Comment: @StephenP Not sure how you didn't understand my comment, but that's not for me to explain. I've retracted my downvote after your explanation, but I doubt this will satisfy OP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read MANIFEST.MF file from JAR using Bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066063/how-to-read-manifest-mf-file-from-jar-using-bash)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
unzip -qc SOME_WAR_FILE.war META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

See [the previous answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7066174/1270789).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I liked the -q (quiet) option as it displays only the contents of the file.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
unzip -p your.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF | cat
```

the `-p` option says:

```
extract files to pipe, no messages
```

That `| cat` isn't really necessary.  It'll print to standard out without it.

Answer (score 0):

A jar or war file is just a standard zip compressed archive, so you can use standard unzip with the `-c` option to direct it to stdout

```
$ file your.jar
your.jar: Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract
$ unzip -c your.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
file contents
file contents
```

Comment: Yes. This displays the file without extracting it. In what way is this wrong?

Comment: I don't have a Linux machine, but wont' this extract the files specified to the temp directory while reading?

Comment: No, it does not.  I just re-ran that command (I of course tested it before posting an answer) while watching my /tmp directory. If something was extracted there it was too fast to see, and it *certainly* did not extract the entire .jar -- if anything it would have been only the one file requested.